# Display/Hide a HTML form after getting a value from a PHP include file

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

What I need to accomplish is to see if a User actually has an existing valid product in his shopping history before he can review on a product. What i want to be able to achieve is to display the review form if he meets the criteria, or not show it at all if he doesnt. My php script is as follows :

```
 <?php
session_start();

//Remove the item from the cart
            $username="root";
            $password="sexy";
            $database="mysql";

            mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
            @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
            $query="SELECT * FROM Orders where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
            $result=mysql_query($query);

            $num=mysql_numrows($result);



        $i=0;
        $canreview = "false";
        while ($i < $num) {
            $orderid = mysql_result($result,$i,"order_id");
            $query2="SELECT * FROM Orderlines where order_id='".$orderid."' AND product_id='".$_SESSION['reviewfruit']."'";
            $result2=mysql_query($query2);
            $num2 = mysql_numrows($result2);
            if($num2 > 0){
                $canreview = "true";
            }

        $i++;
        }
    echo $canreview;
//Re-organize the cart
//array_unshift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'], array_shift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']));
//Clear the URL variables
                mysql_close();
```

?>

and my html form is as follows :

```
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="review">
            <table border=0.2>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tr width=1024>
                        <td><select id = "Rating" name="Rating">
                        <option value="Please Choose">Please Choose</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="Comment" name="Comment" rows=3 width=300 ></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><div id="errorRating"></div></td>
                    <td><div id="errorComment"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type="hidden" id="Product_id" name="Product_id" value="<?php echo $primarykey;?>" />

            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Submit Review" name="submit" id="submit">
            <div id="errorDb"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

What I want to know is how I can use my $canreview variable from my php script to show the form.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: BTW, instead of two queries and a loop, you can calculate `$canreview` with three lines of code. Use an `INNER JOIN` query with `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
if ($canreview) {
    include 'theform.php';
}
```

Comment: `$canreview === "true"` would be more appropriate, the OP is storing the string true/false instead of bool true/false.

Comment: the thing is i have <?php include 'reviewcheck.php'?> before my html form starts at <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="POST">
reviewcheck.php is the script that returns string true or false

Comment: @ValianthX Then you can wrap the form in the mentioned if statement. It is also better to use boolean TRUE/FALSE instead of strings.